# angularjs directive definition using angular.module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please can anyone explain why the following throws an "Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined" error which seems to be tied into the use of module dependency injection with directives(?!).

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', [function() {
    var self = this;
    self.name = "will this work";
    self.items = [
      {
        name: "name 1",
        test: "test 1"
      },
      {
        name: "name 2",
        test: "test 2"
      }
    ];
  }]);

angular.module('app',[])
  .directive('typeahead', [function() {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'type-ahead.html',
      restrict: 'AEC',
      scope: {
        items: '=',
        prompt: '@',
        title: '@',
        subtitle: '@',
        model: '=',
        onSelect: '&'
      }, <...more code>
```

Yet it will work perfectly fine when I remove the

> [ ]

module dependency braces from the directive to read

> angular.module('app').directive('typeahead', ...)

It also works perfectly fine if I define the directive as a cascade following the controller definition i.e.

```
angular.module('app', [])
      .controller('MainCtrl', [function() {
        var self = this;
        self.name = "will this work";
        self.items = [
          {
            name: "name 1",
            test: "test 1"
          },
          {
            name: "name 2",
            test: "test 2"
          }
        ];
      }])

    .directive('typeahead', [function() {
        return {
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `angular.module('app', [])` creates a module, `angular.module('app')` gets already created module. When you create a module again, yes obviously it is created again and anything registered before is gone for good.

Comment: Thanks - makes perfect sense now

Answer (score 2):

You are running into Angular's [Creation versus Retrieval](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#creation-versus-retrieval) Problem:

> Beware that using angular.module('myModule', []) will create the module myModule and overwrite any existing module named myModule. Use angular.module('myModule') to retrieve an existing module.

The first time you run `angular.module('app',[])`, Angular will create a module called `app`. Next time, you only need to run `angular.module('app')`, Angular will try to load the existing module `app`.

Since you call `angular.module('app',[])` once again, module `app` has been re-initialized. That's why `MainCtrl` is undefined now.